# Subtracting 1 column from multiple columns

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6, c=7:9, d=10:12, e=13:15)
```

```
a  b  c  d   e
1  4  7  10  13
2  5  8  11  14
3  6  9  12  15
```

Is it possible to subtract 'column a' from all of the other columns without doing each calculation individually?

I have a dataset of 1001 columns and would like to know if it is possible to do so without doing 1000 calculations manually.

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for  `df - df$a`?

Comment: `df[-1] - df[[1]]`?

Comment: Or with `dplyr`: `df %>% mutate(across(-a, function(x) x - a))`?

Comment: @MartinGal more concisely, it can be `df %>% mutate(across(-a, ~ . - a))` or `df %>% mutate(across(-a, `-`, a))`

Comment: @DarrenTsai That's great. I'm still struggling with those notations.

Comment: @MartinGal Note that the "minus" in my second version of code should be quoted by "backticks", or it won't work.(The "backtick" symbol cannot be displayed in comments)

Comment: @DarrenTsai You can escape the backtick in comments with`\\`` see  `df %>% mutate(across(-a, \`-\`, a))`

Comment: @GKi Oh I didn't know that. I'm stuck with it many times. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=4:6, c=7:9, d=10:12, e=13:15)
#Isolate
df1 <- df[,1,drop=F]
#Substract
dfr <- cbind(df1,as.data.frame(apply(df[,-1],2,function(x) x-df1)))
names(dfr)<-names(df)

  a b c d  e
1 1 3 6 9 12
2 2 3 6 9 12
3 3 3 6 9 12
```

Comment: This is a lot more complex, less efficient and harder to follow than `df[-1] <- df[-1] - df[[1]]` but gives the same result

Comment: I am new to R so I didn't understand the above without and example to follow.